# Troubleshooting error MSB4018: The "SetInclusionListEntry" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: ant, msbuild, jenkins, vsto

I am using Jenkins with Ant to build a VSTO Project on our build machine.  Yesterday it was building fine, now today I am getting the following error:

```
   [exec] Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\ProjectDir\workspace\ProjectDir\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
     [exec] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(668,9): error MSB4018: The "SetInclusionListEntry" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\ProjectDir\workspace\ProjectDir\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
     [exec] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(668,9): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\ProjectDir\workspace\ProjectDir\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
```

I reverted the code to the last known working commit. The code builds fine on my local dev machine.

Any idea about what could have changed on the build machine to cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I should know when I didn't change anything that Windows Update's still can.

[image]

I looked at my Windows Update history and saw that an update failed to apply to the VSTO runtime. So I reapplied the update by right clicking on the failed update going to **View Details** going to the link under more information downloading and running the package found on the [KB article page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2796590).

Once the framework was repaired the build worked as normal.